# Outlook getAsync Email Content img tag not working properly

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I already get the html content of the email and its working fine. But i have problem, one of my email has screenshot embedded to the body. Now I can get the list of images ( see the image below )

[image]

But the img tag that outlook is giving me like this;

`<img class="x_w-1378 x_h-886" size="349452" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" src="cid:9ea35d14-aa1e-47d6-9c5b-b31ced143981" style="max-width:100%">`

`<img width="643" height="359" id="x_Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01D8A327.B5A0B590" style="width:6.6979in; height:3.7395in">`

Now how would i know that this image is for this attachment and vice versa.

This is my code for getting the email body

```html
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", {coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html}, 
function (result) { 
  var body = result.value.trim();
  console.log(var);
});
```

Hope anyone can answer me or give me some tips

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The source of the image is declared with the `cid:` prefix in the following way:

```
src="cid:9ea35d14-aa1e-47d6-9c5b-b31ced143981"
```

The corresponding attachment will have the same name or the value from the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property (the DASL name is  "urn:schemas:mailheader:content-id"). You can use EWS to extract this bit.

The [isInline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentdetails?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-attachmentdetails-isinline-member) property gets a value that indicates whether the attachment should be displayed in the body of the item. See [Office.AttachmentDetails interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentdetails?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-attachmentdetails-attachmenttype-member) for available properties of attachments in web add-ins.

Comment: Yes i know the isInline property. I dont have a problem on that. I just want to know that this image is for this img tag on the html content, if the outlook is giving me this kind of img tags 

`<img class="x_w-1378 x_h-886" size="349452" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" src="cid:9ea35d14-aa1e-47d6-9c5b-b31ced143981" style="max-width:100%">`

`<img width="643" height="359" id="x_Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01D8A327.B5A0B590" style="width:6.6979in; height:3.7395in">`

There's no way i can compare it to the attachment using the Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments

Comment: We can compare the attachment by using cid:: prefix .The source of the image is declared in the cid::prefix and we can compare it with the attachment name we get from attachment API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-messageread-getattachmentcontentasync-member(1)